# Troubleshooting error returned by dash table

Tags: python, html, plotly-dash

I'm trying to display a table in Dash. I import dash_table and I get an error: 
KeyError: 'map'

The python page is simply:

```
import dash
import dash_table
import pandas as pd
import dash_html_components as html

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
        html.H3('A Table')
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

The error appears as soon as the page is loaded. Commenting out 'import dash_table' makes the error go away. As you can see, I'm not even creating a table.
I am running python 3.6.3. I am not using a virtual environment.
Are other people getting this error message? Is there an alternative to dash_table?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you forgot specify `dash_table.DataTable()`, and specify only name 'A Table' as a `html.H3`.

Code:

```
import dash
import dash_table
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Item': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3],
                   'Status': ["First", "Second", "Third",
                              "First", "Second", "First"],
                   'Value': [2000, 3490, 542, 641, 564, 10]})

app.layout = html.Div([
        html.H3('A Table', style={'textAlign': 'center'}),
        dash_table.DataTable(
            id='table',
            columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns],
            data=df.to_dict("rows"),
            )
        ]
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Output:
[image: Your Table]

You can learn more about how to using dash-table properly - just look in docs [here](https://dash.plot.ly/datatable). Hope it helps you